# Python, Code128.png gets blurred

Tags: python, size, barcode, code128

[image]

When the stored data get more and I resize the image I lose details and the code can't get scaned.

I want to create a Code128.png with a certain size(30mm*10mm). I'm not able to find a solution to this problem. I'm able to change the Size, but the Image gets unreadable(blurred).

first attempt:

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from pystrich.code128 import Code128Encoder

 EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
 ean = EAN('H6.2.9-LED1-D0-USB-SM00', writer=ImageWriter())
 fullname = ean.save(r'C:\Users\Pictures\Code128')
 image = Image.open(r'C:\User\Pictures\Code128.png')
 new_image = image.resize((150, 20))
 new_image.save(r'C:\Users\Pictures\M_Code128.png')
```

second attempt:

```
barcode = Code128.Code128("123456789",barHeight=.9*inch,barWidth = 1.2)
barcode.save(r'C:\Users\Pictures\P_Code128.png'
```

third attempt:

```
 encoder = Code128Encoder('123456789')
 encoder.save(r'C:\Users\Pictures\Code128.png')
 img = Image(r'C:\Users\Pictures\Code128.png', width= 10*mm, 
 height=20*mm)
 img.save(r'C:\Users\Pictures\T_Code128.png')
```

Comment: "a Code128.png with a certain size(30mm*10mm)." What does this mean? What is special about that file name? How are you deciding the size of the image? Images on a computer are stored, and thus sized, in *pixels*, not any physical dimension. You need some kind of assumption of DPI to get a physical size. "I'm able to change the Size, but the Image gets unreadable(blurred)." Okay, so: the problem is ultimately about *resizing* an image, right? Does it actually matter what code you use to create the image? I think what matters is *how detailed* that image is.

Comment: Basically: how are we supposed to have any idea what this image result is supposed to look like? Why should we expect that the image, at a specific size, should be un-blurry?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Code128.png is a image of a code128 barcode. I need a certain size to put it in a PDF. I have problem with resizing. You right, I lose details so the Code can't get scaned.

Comment: "I need a certain size to put it in a PDF" - How exactly are you creating the PDF? If you're using an editing program, did you try using the program features to resize the image while designing the PDF? If you're creating it programmatically with a PDF library, did you try looking for resizing functionality in the documentation for that library? PDF is fundamentally a vector format, after all; the underlying image size shouldn't matter all that much. "I lose details so the Code can't get scaned." How does the scanning work? Are you printing the PDF first? If so, at what resolution?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm using repotlab to create PDF's. I'm building a PDF(Label)-Generator. I have a Table where I insert the data. It already works with a picture of a Datamatrix. The Picture gets also insert in the table. In my third attempt I using the same library I'm using for the DataMatrix. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's still not clear to me: a) what the PDF looks like when you're done; b) why that result is not acceptable; c) exactly what you do with the PDF after creating it.